# unable to handle request error 500 php email

Tags: php, arrays

Edit* thanks for the input thus far. I downloaded javabeans and it was a big help removing all the small errors flooding my code. I've got it almost completely working, except for one section

```
//Part numbers, if any

$partNumbers = range(1,12);
$part =array();
foreach($partNumbers as $value){
    $part[$value] = 0;
    if(!empty($_POST['partnumber'.$value])){
        $part[$value] = $_POST['partnumber'.$value];
    }
}
//Check for part numbers
if($part[1] && $part[2]  && $part[3] && $part[4] && $part[5] && $part[6] && $part[7] && $part[8] && $part[9] && $part[10] && $part[11] && $part[12] ="0")
    {
    $email_body .= "No part numbers where listed.\r\n\r\n";
}
else{
     $email_body .= "Part numbers listed:\r\n";
     foreach( $partNumbers as $value){
         if($part[$value] !="0"){
             $email_body .="{$part['$value']}\r\n";}
      }
}
```

This returns the "Part numbers Listed:" Line from the else statement, weather none 1 and/or all part number fields are populated or not.

*edit

So I've been working on our sites quote request page, which is a form to email format. (site =>> http://www.tomanthermosonics.com/form-page.html). When i go to submit the form, i get the unable to handle request error. I know my site can send emails, before i divulged into the code i did a few small test runs successfully. I'm thinking the error has to be somewhere in the php file which is used to generate the email. My best guess is its happening somewhere down the line in transferring all the data from stored arrays to the emails body.

Also, thanks for reading and/or any input on design best practices, or where i went wrong!

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    //This page should not be accessed directly. Need to submit the form.
    echo "error; you need to submit the form!";
}
//base customer input

$fname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lname = $_POST['lastname'];
$visitor_email = $_POST['email'];


//Validate first
if(empty($fname)||empty($visitor_email)||empty($lname)) 
{
    echo "Name and email are mandatory!";
    exit;
}

if(IsInjected($visitor_email))
{
    echo "Bad email value!";
    exit;
}

//Add base info
$fields = array(
    'phone' => 'phonenumber',
    'fax' => 'faxnumber',
    'web' => 'website',
    'company' => 'company',
    'street' => 'street',
    'city' => 'city',
    'state' => 'state',
    'zip' => 'zipcode',
    'description' => 'description'  
    );
$baseinfo = array();

foreach($fields as $key => $field){
    $baseinfo[$key] = "0";
    if(!empty($_POST[$field])){
        $baseinfo[$key] = $_POST[$field];}
    };  


//Part numbers, if any

$partNumbers = range(1,12);
$part =array();
foreach($partNumbers as $value){
    $part[$value] = 0;
    if(!empty($_POST['partnumber'.$value])){
        $part[$value] = $_POST['partnumber'.$value];
    };
};

//fixture fields

$fixtureFields = array(
    'type' => 'machinetype',
    'othertype' => 'othermachine',
    'nest' => 'nestmaterial',
    'special' => 'fixtureneeds',
    'movement' => 'fixturemovement'
    'other' => 'fotherneeds');
$fixturetooling = array();

foreach($fixtureFields as $key => $field){
    $fixturetooling[$key] = "0";
    if($_POST[$field] != 0 || !empty([$_POST[$field])){
        $fixturetooling[$key] = $_POST[$field];
    };    
};

//Horn Fields

$hornFields = array(
    'material' => 'hornmaterial',
    'finish' => 'hornfinish',
    'frequency' => 'hornfrequency',
    'shape' => 'hornshape'
    'special' => 'specialneeds',
    'facedim' => 'facedim',
    'basedim' => 'basedim',
    'facediameter' => 'facediameter',
    'basediameter' => 'basediameter',
    'stud' => 'studsize'
    'other' => 'hotherneeds'); 

$horntooling = array();

foreach($hornFields as $key => $field){
    $horntooling[$key] = "0";
    if($_POST[$field] != 0 || !empty([$_POST[$field])){
        $horntooling[$key] = $_POST[$field];
    };

}; 

//Begin formatting email 


$email_from = 'Sales@TomanThermoSonics.com';

$email_subject = "Quote Request from $fname $lname";

//body of email

$email_body = "$fname $lname has requested a quote.\r\n";
$email_body .= "\r\n";

//Check for description
if($baseinfo['description'] !="0")
    {
    $email_body .= "Description of Needs: \r\n\r\n";
    $email_body .= "$baseinfo['description']\r\n\r\n";
    }
    else{
          $email_body .= "No description was provided\r\n\r\n";
          }


//Check for part numbers
if($part[1] && $part[1] && $part[2] && $part[1] && $part[3] && $part[4] && $part[5] && $part[6] && $part[7] && $part[8] && $part[9] && $part[10] && $part[11] && $part[12] ="0")
    {
    $email_body .= "No part numbers where listed.\r\n\r\n";
}
else{
     $email_body .= "Part numbers listed:\r\n";
     foreach( $part as $value){
         if(value !="0"){
             $email_body .="$value\r\n";};
      };
};

$email_body .= "\r\n\r\n";

//Provide Fixture Info
$email_body .="Fixture Info: \r\n";





switch(!="0"){
        case $fixturetooling['type']:
              @email_body .= "Fixture Type: $fixturetooling[type]\r\n";            
        case $fixturetooling['othertype']:
              @email_body .= "Fixture Type: $fixturetooling[type]\r\n";            
        case $fixturetooling['nest']:
              @email_body .= "Nest material: $fixturetooling[type]\r\n";               
        case $fixturetooling['special']:
              @email_body .= "Special needs: $fixturetooling[type]\r\n";               
        case $fixturetooling['movement']:
              @email_body .= "Fixture movement: $fixturetooling[type]\r\n";            
        case $fixturetooling['other']:
              @email_body .= "Other needs: $fixturetooling[type]\r\n";
               }
$email)body .="\r\n\r\n";
$email_body .="Horn Info: \r\n";
//Provide UltrasonicHorn Info
switch(!="0"){
              case $horntooling['material']:
                   @email_body .= "Type of horn material: $horntooling['material']\r\n";
              case $horntooling['finish']:
                   @email_body .= "Horn finish: $horntooling['finish']\r\n";
              case $horntooling['frequency']:
                   @email_body .= "Horn frequency: $horntooling['frequency']\r\n";
              case $horntooling['shape']:
                   @email_body .= "Horn shape: $horntooling['shape']\r\n";
              case $horntooling['facedim']:
                   @email_body .= "Horn face Length x Width: $horntooling['facedim']\r\n";
              case $horntooling['basedim']:
                   @email_body .= "Horn base Length x Width: $horntooling['basedim']\r\n";
              case $horntooling['facediameter']:
                   @email_body .= "Horn face diameter: $horntooling['facediameter']\r\n";
              case $horntooling['basediameter']:
                   @email_body .= "Horn base diameter: $horntooling['basediameter']\r\n";
              case $horntooling['stud']:
                   @email_body .= "Stud size: $horntooling['stud']\r\n";
              case $horntooling['other']:
                   @email_body .= "Other horn needs: $horntooling['other']\r\n";

              }
$email_body .= "\r\n\r\n";

$email_body .="Customer Info";
$email_body ."Name: $fname $lname\r\n";
$email_body .="Company: $baseinfo['company']\r\n";
$email_body .="Email Address: $email\r\n";
$email_body .="Phone number: $baseinfo['phone']\r\n";
$email_body .="Fax number: $baseinfo['fax']\r\n";   
$email_body .="Address:\r\n $baseinfo['street']\r\n";
$email_body .="$baseinfo['city'], $baseinfo['state'] $baseinfo['zip']\r\n"; 










$to = "sales@tomanthermosonics.com";//<== update the email address
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";

$headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
//Send the email!
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//done. redirect to thank-you page.
header('Location: thank-you.html');


// Function to validate against any email injection attempts
function IsInjected($str)
{
  $injections = array('(\n+)',
              '(\r+)',
              '(\t+)',
              '(%0A+)',
              '(%0D+)',
              '(%08+)',
              '(%09+)'
              );
  $inject = join('|', $injections);
  $inject = "/$inject/i";
  if(preg_match($inject,$str))
    {
    return true;
  }
  else
    {
    return false;
  }
}

?>
```

Thanks for the quick input thus far; i am downloading an ide currently. I am struggling to understand how i can get the switch statement to evaluate to true in these circumstances.

i am trying to change it to

```
switch(!"0")
    case $somearray['somekey']:
```

am i better off using a string of if statements or a foreach?

Comment: 500 error: check your logs

Comment: I believe a comma is missing in your $hormFields array, after 'studsize'.

Comment: Always check your server error logs for the reason of a 500 error. But you have a lot of syntax errors in your code here. Use a proper IDE that will highlight syntax errors for you.

Comment: @Dexter0015 There are a lot more than that one missing comma. There's a few other missing commas, mismatched brackets, the switch statements are wrong... that's just the start of it.

Comment: @aynber, you're right, after some times I admit I stopped searching.

Comment: Switch statements are for checking different values of a single variable, like doing different things if $x is 1, 2, 3, or b. You'll need to rethink the logic of what you're trying to do there.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP has quite a few errors:-

Lines 68, 85 and 91

```
'movement' => 'fixturemovement'
'shape' => 'hornshape'
'stud' => 'studsize'
```

Missing a comma at the end of the line

Line 74 and 98

```
if($_POST[$field] != 0 || !empty([$_POST[$field])){
if($_POST[$field] != 0 || !empty([$_POST[$field])){
```

You have an extra [ in your empty function

Line 120

```
$email_body .= "$baseinfo['description']\r\n\r\n";
```

Variable needs to be wrapped in curly brackets "{}"

And to be honest I've stopped here as most of these issues are the same sort of problem. As people in the comments have pointed out, these are actually pretty simple mistakes any PHP IDE should be able to pick up for you before you even get around to testing your code. You should use one as it'll make your life much easier when it comes to issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of bugs in your code. Firstly, you have problem with **array** `$fixtureFields, $hornFields` you forgot to add

> ,

[image]

[image]

Then, you have to replace it:

```
$email_body .= "$baseinfo['description']\r\n\r\n";
```

To:

```
$email_body .= $baseinfo['description']."\r\n\r\n";
```

Then, you have to fix your [switch](http://php.net/switch) statement:

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks,i found a sandbox and found most of the errors you pointed out.

Comment: It's not a good idea to post images of code. It's better to post just the code itself.